# ¿ Como Invocar EJB desde un Server remoto a otro server.. utilizando WILDFLY 10 y JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, aplicación-web, ejb, wildfly

Actualmente desarrollo una aplicación web en JSP con WILDFLY 10. Actualmente mi aplicación esta dividida en módulos pero todo lo despliego con un mismo EAR.

La idea mía es dividir la aplicación en varios modulos, un EAR que sea un ejb remoto el cual maneja toda la parte de consultas a base de datos y demas y por otro lado varios wars por separados que llamen remotamente a ese EJB, todo esto con el fin de a la hora de tener un cambio solo desplegar el componente que necesito y no toda la aplicación en general ya que actualmente todo lo tengo en un mismo EAR ya que es la unica forma de que mis wars puedan llamar al EJB.

En la documentación de WIldlfy explica como hacerlo pero no es una documentación muy clara.

[EJB invocations from a remote server instance](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+server+instance)

Quisiera que alguien me explicara paso a paso como hacerlo y si es posible en una maquina windows.

Answer (score 2):

#### Java EE 7

Cuando despliegas un EJB en el servidor de aplicaciones, este hace un registro de ellos vía JNDI -llamado binding- con los siguientes datos:

```
java:global/[<application-name>]/<module-name>/<bean-name>!<fully-qualified-bean-interface-name>
```

Donde:

- application-name: es el nombre de la aplicación. **Solo necesario si se ha desplegado un EAR**. Se deduce por:

  - el nombre del EAR
  - el valor de `<display></display>` del archivo `application.xml` dentro de `META-INF`.
- module-name: es el nombre del módulo al cual pertenece el bean (archivos .jar, .war) sin la extensión. Esto puede ser sobreescrito en el `ejb-jar.xml`.
- bean-name: indica el nombre simple del bean.
- fully-qualified-bean-interface-name: indica el nombre calificado (con todo y paquete) del bean o de la interface (en caso sea un EJB remoto).

Esta estructura fue impuesta a partir de la especificación 3.1 de EJB y la puedes utilizar en Java EE 7+. Antes de esto, cada vendor tenía su propia estructura JNDI, no permitiendo hacer las aplicaciones totalmente portables.

Existen también dos tipos más de JNDI:

- `java:module/ejbName!fullEjbInterfaceName`: se usa cuando el EJB remoto está en el mismo módulo.
- `java:app/moduleName/ejbName!fullEjbInterfaceName`: se usa cuando el EJB remoto se encuentra en otro módulo pero en la misma aplicación.

#### Creando EJBs remotos sin estado

Para crear un EJB remoto basta con crear una interface y una clase que la implemente y que, además, referencie a la interfaz por medio de la anotación `@Remote`.

```
public class CalculadoraRemote {
    public int sumar(int n1, int n2);
    public int restar(int n1, int n2);
    public int multiplicar(int n1, int n2);
    public double dividir(int n1, int n2);
}

@Remote(CalculadoraRemote.class);
public class CalcuadoraBean implements CalculadoraRemote {

    // métodos
}
```

Cuando desplegemos esto, el JNDI será:

```
java:global/Calculadora/calculadoraejbs/CalculadoraBean!pe.mitsugami.ejb.CalculadoraRemote
```

### Haciendo lookup (búsqueda) de EJBs remotos

Par hacer un `lookup` de un EJB, lo haremos por medio de las propiedades del JNDI:

- application-name: **Solo necesario si se ha desplegado un EAR**.
- module-name: lo mismo, el nombre del jar que contiene el/los EJB.
- bean-name: lo mismo
- fully-qualified-bean-interface-name: lo mismo

#### Componentes No-JavaEE

```
final Map<String, String> propiedadesJndi = new HashTable<>();
propiedadesJndi.put(Context.URL_PGK_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.client.naming");
final Context contexto = new InitialContext(propiedadesJndi);

// propiedades JNDI
String appName = ""; // o el nombre del EAR en caso hayas desplegado un EAR
String moduleName = "calcuadoraejbs";
String beanName = CalculadoraBean.class.getSimpleName();
String fullyBeanName = CalculadoraBean.class.getName();

// procedemos con la búsqueda
CalculadoraRemote calculadora = (CalculadoraRemote) contexto.lookup("java:global/"+appName+"/"+beanName+"!"+fullyBeanName);
```

#### Componentes Java EE

Para componentes Java EE podemos aprovechar la anotación `@EJB` para inyectar la dependencia del EJB remoto.

```
@EJB
private CalculadoraRemote calculadora;
```

Esto funcionará si solo tienes una implementación de `CalculadoraRemote`, si tienes más no funcionará porque tendrás un problema de **dependencias ambiguas**. Esto se soluciona por medio del atributo `name` de `Stateless|Stateful|Singleton`:

```
@Stateless(name = "calculadoraCientifica")
@Remote(CalculadoraRemote.class)
public class CalculadoraCientifica implements CalculadoraRemote { }

@Stateless(name = "calculadoraSimple")
@Remote(CalculadoraRemote.class)
public class CalculadoraSimple implements CalculadoraRemote { }
```

E inyectamos:

```
@EJB(name = "calculadoraCientifica")
private CalculadoraRemote calculadora;
```

También puedes inyectar un EJB remoto indicando el nombre JNDI de forma explícita por medio del atributo `lookup` de la anotación `@EJB`.

```
@EJB(lookup = "java:global/calculadoraejbs/CalculadoraBean!pe.mitsugami.ejb.CalculadoraRemote")
private CalculadoraRemote calculadora;
```